# what is the difference between razorview and razorlayout in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I used razor pages and want to create a razor page partial view.
I saw two options one **razor view**  and another **razor layout**, what is different between the two? Which is better for a *partial view*?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter which template you use to create a partial for Razor Pages. In both cases, you will need to replace the existing content and rename the file. A partial is just a single Razor file that doesn't have an `@page` directive.

You could also use the ViewStart and View Imports templates. The Razor Page template could also be used, but you would also need to delete the PageModel class file that gets generated.

More about Partials in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages